# Cannot resolve symbol 'ToTable' EF Core 2.2.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I updated my dependencies as follow, in a dot net core app and looks like something got changed in ef libraries because to table is no longer resolved under `modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>.ToTable('EntityTable');`

Libs updated (from git track)

```
-<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4"/>
-<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.4"/>
-<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.4"/>
-<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3"/>
++<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
++<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.2.0" />
++<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.0" />
++<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.0" />
++<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
```

As I updated them one by one, the issue appeared after those 2 (any of those, when updated, both caused the errors in the DbContext)

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.0" />
```

As an attempt to fix I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational as well, but it did not fix it.

My context looks as follows:

```
using Itb.Database.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Itb.Database.Context
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<ApprovedMember> ApprovedMembers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApprovedMember>().ToTable("ApprovedMember");
        }
    }
}
```

I have dotnet --version = 2.2.101 (latest so far)

Hope you can help me to fix this :)

Thanks!

Deps as resolved deps
[Deps from proj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7E9Y.png)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Have you tried `dotnet restore`? Or even simply restarting Visual Studio? Does `dotnet build` from the command line work?

Comment: @DavidG tried restrore + build. Restarted JetBrains Rider (i don't use vs) + cache reset / clear. Don't know what else to do :))

Comment: And `dotnet build` gives you the same error? Any other warnings? If you revert the changes you made above, does that fix it?

Comment: @DavidG. Just opened the project in VS, the error is there as well, but a bit more explicit, but i still don't get what's wrong.

'EntityTypeBuilder<ApprovedMember>' does not contain a definition for 'ToTable' and no extension method 'ToTable' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder<ApprovedMember>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @DavidG hi, yes, same errors. If i revert to 2.1.4 it works perfectly

Comment: What does this code do: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalEntityTypeBuilderExtensions.ToTable(modelBuilder.Entity<ApprovedMember>(), "ApprovedMember");`?

Comment: Also, when you run `dotnet --version`, is the current directory inside the folder where your project is? You don't happen to have a `gloabal.json` file in there?

Comment: @DavidG Cannot resolve symbol 'RelationalEntityTypeBuilderExtensions'
dotnet --version globally (cmd in random dir).  In the project dir i have same version 2.2.101. No global.json file :)

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure you don't have a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`. Can you check that exists and is resolving properly?

Comment: @DavidG photo attached to the question / issue, please check it yourself, as you can see it seems resolved ...

Comment: I'm at a loss. Can you maybe try compiling on another computer?

Comment: @DavidG removed all packages and reinstalled all of them with latest version (same version i updated at) and it worked :| Thanks for the help anyway :))

Comment: adding Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package fixed mine

Answer (score 11):

`ToTable` is under Microsoft Entity Framework Core Relational Assembly. you need to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions)

Comment: It was already installed. Check comments and read the entire question ;)

Comment: do you mean that Microsoft's Reference is wrong? :) You probably going to regret for not triple checking your solution. sorry mate

Comment: are you working with single assembly? or you have multiple?

Comment: my friend check the screenshot attached. Trust me, that was not the issues, check the comments, I fixed it ;) I know my reputation is low, but i have some years of experience with dotnet and java as well :)

Comment: In my case, I had a library for .Net Framework 4.7.1 and I have the package EntityFrameworkCore. I cannot remove the error until I've Installed the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package. Thanks